# How to make a histogram smaller inside another line plot

Tags: plot, graphics, data-visualization, line

I wish to make a plot just like the following:

[image]

```
plot(cp1cold,"overall",col=4,ylab="RR",xlab="Temperature",xlim=c(-5,35),
ylim=c(-0.5,3.5),axes=F,lwd=1.5)
lines(cp1hot,"overall",ci="area",col=2,lwd=1.5)
axis(1,at=-1:7*5)
axis(2,at=c(1:7*0.5))
title("Overall cumulative association and temperature distribution")
mtext("London 1993-2006",cex=0.75)
par(new=T)
hist(lndn$tmean,xlim=c(-5,35),ylim=c(0,1200),axes=F,ann=F,col=grey(0.95),breaks=30)
abline(v=quantile(lndn$tmean,c(0.01,0.99)),lty=2)
abline(v=cen,lty=3)
axis(4,at=0:4*100)
mtext("Freq",4,line=2.5,at=200,cex=0.8)
```

Which code can be found here: https://github.com/gasparrini/2014_gasparrini_BMCmrm_Rcodedata/blob/master/03.graphs.R

However, no matter what I try, when I try using my own data my plot comes with a huge histogram.
Do someone know how to make this histogram smaller?

[image]

OBS: I have tried using a different layout, putting each plot in one line layer, but it was not aesthetically pleasing

Answer (score 1):

Your data have very high values four your histogram. Your upper limit value (1200) is lower than your higher values. Because of that, your histogram exceeds its boundries. You must change the upper limit value at "ylim=c(0,1200)".